# How can I move a checkbox to the left

Tags: html, css, checkbox

please help me out.

I have been trying to move a checkbox to the left.

Html and CSS

```
<Input type="checkbox" name="" id="" >
```

I tried to float it left. And i have tried to apply margin.

Comment: Please check your question, we cannot see your HTML or CSS. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to find out how to present your code, thanks.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Checkboxes</h2>


<form action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" id="abike" name="bike" value="Bike">
  <label for="bike"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acar" name="car" value="Car">
  <label for="car"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="aboat" name="boat" value="Boat">
  <label for="boat"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>

</html>

Comment: Please read through the link and put the code into your question, not in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```css
Input {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
}
```

You can use this on your CSS and the checkbox will be moved to the left

Or

```css
Input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It not working ‍♂️. Please try it on your device

Comment: can you show me your CSS code and picture of your output?!

Comment: I updated the code with screenshot of code and result, sorry for the late response.